# Materialized view refresh terrible performance degradation

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing, materialized-views

I have materialized view (it uses joins, WITH, partition by; query returns about **42 mln** rows) with 2 simple indexes on it. Only full refresh is used.

The first refresh works fine (it takes ~100 minutes) but second refresh works several days and failed to complete.

Also I dropped indexes and re-run test. It works fine. 
Here is all results (time and redo entries from session statistics):

1) Without indexes, first run
time: 72 min
redo: **42 mln** (it is close to row number)

2) Without indexes, second run
time: 106 min
redo: **84 mln** (42 mln to delete all and 42 mln to insert new)

3) With 2 indexes, first run
time: 99 min
redo: **126 mln** (42 mln for rows and 42 mln for each index)

4) With 2 indexes, second run
time: failed after 48 hours
redo: **453 mln** when failed (I have no idea why it's so huge)

Oracle version:  11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0

The issue was reproduced on different instances&servers. I have no server where it works correctly. I think that it is some kind of bug but can't find anything similar

Comment: Is there a question? (and, more importantly, if there is a question is there any way we could answer it given the lack of information you have presented about the tables, indexes and queries you've used?)

Comment: I can't copy the SQL query but itself it executed about 30 mins. So we need 30 minutes to select data and about 40-60 minutes to insert it. 
The question is "why rebuilding of the index is 50 times slower then bulding  and needs abnormal huge redo size?" 

Indexes are simple one varchar2-column.

Comment: @Vladislav Thank you for the hint that refreshing is much faster without indexes while querying these materialized views is still much faster than running the complex query alone!

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note, between Versions 10 and 11 Oracle changed the default value of the optional "atomic_refresh" parameter to the dbms_mview.refresh() API from FALSE to TRUE.

If atomic_refresh = TRUE then a full refresh will be done via DELETE/INSERT. If atomic_refresh=FALSE then, if possible, Oracle will do the refresh via a TRUNCATE/INSERT with parallel DML. MUCH faster, but with the following caveat: If, however, you are refreshing more than one mview at a time then you will need to think about this because atomic_refresh=TRUES ensures that all refreshes happen in a single transaction, FALSE does not - which may be problematic.

EDIT: My bad, that change in behaviour happened between Oracle 9 and 10. Not 10 and 11. There is also the side effect that truncate/insert means that the MVIEW contains no data over the rebuild which may be problematic for users querying it. Do some research, figure out what your business needs are, and go from there. You could also drop the indexes, do the refresh, and then recreate the indexes to speed things up.

Comment: If indexes will be droped then there is no sense to use MV

Comment: If you drop them just for the rebuild and then recreate them immediately after, the rebuild will run a lot faster and with less redo, and the end result is still an indexed materialized dataset that is far more efficient than a complex query at runtime.

Comment: Yes, only 6 minutes needed to rebuild the indexes, but 60 minutes needed to rebuild data and during this time there will be no possibility for fast data search.

Comment: Well, it does take time to completely rebuild large data sets. Maybe you need to re-evaluate and look at fast refresh based on partition change tracking or other mechanisms - because re-generating large data sets unnecessarily is always going to be a performance problem.